# JavaScript setTimeout function not executing as expected

Tags: javascript, forms, iframe, settimeout

I'm driving myself crazy here trying to figure out why this script is no longer executing as expected (it was working great yesterday, but I made a few minor changes and didn't back it up...now I can't figure out what the problem is).

```
    <form method="POST" name="inventory_check" id="inventory_check">    
        <input type="text" name="stock_part" id="part_input">
        <input type="hidden" name="site" value="2">
        <input type="submit" value="Check Stock" id="submit">
    </form>

    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['stock_part'])) {
            $part = strtoupper($_GET['stock_part']);
            $site = $_POST['site'];
            $filename = 'system/inventory/'.$part.'.txt';
            if(file_exists($filename)) {
                $handle = fopen($filename, 'r');
                $content = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
                $content = trim($content, '&l0O(10U');
                $content = trim($content, 'E');
                fclose($handle);
                date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
                $mod_date = (filemtime($filename));
                $current_date = time();
                $subtract_date = ($current_date - $mod_date);
                $subtract_date = ($subtract_date/3600);
                if ($subtract_date <= 12) {
                    $stock = number_format($content);
                    echo '<script>document.inventory_check.style.display="visible";</script>';
                    echo '<div id="stock_results">There are '.$stock.' '.$part.' in stock.</div>';
                }
                else {
                    echo 'File too old.';
                }
            }
            else {
                echo '<iframe src="http://example.com/inventory_check.php?part='.$part.'&site='.$site.'" height="50" width="150"></iframe>';
                echo '<script>document.inventory_check.style.display="none";</script>';
                echo '<div align="center"><img src="http://www.aifittingsproto.com/images/load.gif"><br /><br />Searching</div>';
                echo '<script>setTimeOut("recheck()", 2000);</script>';
            }
        }
    ?>
    <script>
    function recheck() {
        document.inventory_check.stock_part.value="<?php echo $part ?>";
        document.inventory_check.site.value="<?php echo $site ?>";
        document.inventory_check.submit();
    }
    </script>
```

Basically this checks stock of a certain item on our internal servers (different domain than web server).  What I'm trying to accomplish is the user keys in the part number...first it checks if the ftp-ed file exists on our server..if so, it checks the time it checks if its fresher than 12hrs, and then displays it if so.  If not, it opens an iframe and sends the variables to our internal server for processing, which all works as expected.  My issue is, I need to be able to have it recheck if the file exists after variables are passed through the iframe.  I attempted to set this up by resending the variables and submitting the form every 2 seconds.  Looking at the source, all the variables are populating as expected, etc. but it is not looping through and resubmitting the form.  Any suggestions why this is failing, or a better approach?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the output that your code produces, instead of the server-side code itself. I can already see that your `setTimeout` call uses a string as a parameter, which is deprecated in favor of function callbacks.

Comment: The output seems to be working correctly to a point.  If the file exists, it displays it correctly and as expected.  If the file is too old, it displays "File too old".  However, if the file does not exist, the iframe is produced, runs as expected, the form is hidden, and the loading gif is displayed, that's where it stops.  No action after that point, so it has to be hanging up on the setTimeout call.

Comment: Keep in mind too that I'm not concerned with sanitizing the input, etc.  I'm just trying to get the expected functionality first, which will then be built upon.

Comment: The `setTimeout` function is spelled `setTimeout` - not `setTimeOut`. JavaScript is case-sensitive, so unless you've rolled your own very-similarly-named function, then I'm guessing that's part of the problem

Comment: Sorry, that must've been a typo.  I've tried out a few simplified things.  used `setTimeout("alert('Test')", 2000)` which is working without and issue; however, `setTimeout("window.reload()", 2000)` does not.

Comment: Was able to use: `<script>setTimeout("window.location.href=window.location;", 3500)</script>';` which solved the issue, although I had to change the form method to `GET`.  I will continue to work on the matter and try to get it working using `POST`.

Answer (score 0):

You should try replacing `setTimeout("window.reload()", 2000)` with `setTimeout("window.reload", 2000)`.  My understanding is that you need to pass functions without the brackets for timeouts.